# How to Save login credentials like Username and Password in Webview

Tags: java, android, webview

Currently, I am still in the process of learning Android development so please excuse me if this question of mine is not easily understandable for you.

I created an Android app of a website and that website has a login interface and i want to save the users data so they don't have to login every time. Now, is it possible to save user's Username and Password?

Since the `setSavePassword` method is deprecated, I can not find another way to implement saving Username and Password. I have read about `SharedPreferences`, JavaScript and Autofill several times, but I don't know how to properly implement them into my app. Because from most of what I have read, it is suggested that it will need a login page first to save the Username and Password.

This is my WebView code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mywebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("");
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    public static class mywebClient extends WebViewClient {
        
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: About the legal part, you probably should be asking [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/), definitely not on SO. It would be good to talk to your institute's authorities as well about integrating with their site.

Comment: the website developer can implement cookie based solution to remember the credentials

Comment: @OmkarT On website, the credentials gets saved but not on my app.